# Enable ODP.Net performance counters

Tags: .net, oracle, connection-pooling, windows-server-2008-r2

How can I enable the ODP.Net Performance Counters for my web app???

I'm Using:

- .Net 2.0
- Oracle 11g
- Windows 2008 R2

Comment: Did you modify the registry or the app.config? What have you tried? Which release of odp.net do you use?

Comment: I modified the registry and it still doesn't show up on the performance counters list in windows

Comment: Have you read this: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3877966&#3877966

Comment: Yes I have. It still won't work

Answer (score 6):

Two parts are required.

1. Installing the perfmon counters
   If they are not already installed, follow the instructions here:
   http://blog.bekijkhet.com/2010/01/odpnet-performance-counters-do-not-show.html
2. Enabling/configuring the perfmon counters
   This is done on a per app (or per home directory, per machine, etc) basis. The best writeup I've seen is here:
   http://blog.ilab8.com/2011/09/02/odp-net-pooling-and-connection-request-timed-out
   Note especially the specific steps for 32 bit apps, and for the install/configure/launch order of operations.